# Azure data factory data flow silently NULLing date column

Tags: csv, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to use Azure Data Factory to upsert a CSV into an Azure SQL table. All seemed well until I checked the results. One of the columns is a nullable date. The CSV contains a value like so `1/2/2020 12:00:00 AM`. The data flow silently inserts a `NULL` instead of throwing an error because it didn't like the input. So how can I get my data flow to convert the string to a datetime properly, and then to error out on issues like this in the future? I really don't want silent failures and bad data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The null value is due to incompatible date formats in ADF. You need to do date format conversion.

Is your source date format like this **MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss**?
If so, you can use [Derived column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-derived-column) and add the expression `toString(toTimestamp(<Your_Column_Name>,'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss'),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:SS')` to format this column to String. It solved the `NULL` value. Of course you can choose what the date format you want.

I made a test as follows:

1. My data source is from a csv file and the `EmpDate` is a date type like yours and last row contains a null value.
   [image]
2. Then I add the expression `toString(toTimestamp(EmpDate,'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss'),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:SS')` in the Derived column activity. Here you can choose the date format what you want.
   [image]

3.According to Mark Kromer's suggestion, I Add Conditional Split directly after the Derived Column and check for isNull(EmpDate). Here I use `not(isNull(EmpDate))` expression.
[image]

4. In the end, if the `EmpDate` contains null value, it will go to sink2 else go to sink1.
   [image]
   The row contains null value:
   [image]

Comment: Adding on to Joseph's answer ... if you don't want your data flow to sink rows that fail this casting, then use a Conditional Split directly after the Derived Column and check for isNull(EmpDate). If null, then write to an error log. Else, continue on normal path.

Comment: @MarkKromer thanks! But is there a way to set it as a default that if a column fails to convert that the whole dataflow fails?

Comment: Default is continue on casting failure, set to NULL. To set your own custom behavior, you'll use this technique.

Comment: Thanks @Mark Kromer, according to his advice, I've updated my answer.

Comment: Hope  my answer is helpful for you @John .

Comment: @JosephXu Thank you for your well-researched answer. Actually I found a workaround. I didn't realize that Azure SQL supports the BulkCopy command through ADO.NET. I thought it didn't in the past. I have existing code that BulkCopys' to a temp table and then merges the rows 4000 at a time so as not to lock the table. Thank you, though!