# Azure Data Factory REST call shows all datetime values as null

Tags: json, rest, azure-data-factory, freshworks

I have an ADF data flow which uses a pre-defined data set of type rest as the source. From the moment the get request is made, ADF shows all datetime values as null. Questions such as [Azure data factory data flow silently NULLing date column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63625287/azure-data-factory-data-flow-silently-nulling-date-column) suggest that it is an issue in how adf is casting the value, and that I should intercept the value before that point and apply my own casting logic. Since the values are presented as null from the get, I can't see how I could intercept the value before it is cast.

I know these values to be non-null when I make this rest call in another environment (curl, postman etc). Hoping someone has some insight. I would like to avoid processing the data outside of ADF as an intermediate step if possible.

Here is an example json body which shows the format the date objs are returned in any alternative environment:

```
       "stats": {
        "ticket_id": 100000549322,
        "resolved_at": null,
        "created_at": "2023-01-04T19:09:19Z",
        "updated_at": "2023-01-04T19:09:22Z"
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the projection tab of the source tile you can select the default formatting of a data type
[image]